# TypeORM AWS RDS Proxy Integration

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, amazon-rds-proxy

I am trying to use RDS proxy with TypeORM in a nestjs application. RDS Proxy uses IAM authentication, because of which I am getting authentication error after 15 minutes. Please let me know if there is a way to make typeorm refresh the token before it gets expire. (Type orm is loaded as part of app module in the nestjs lambda function)

Comment: What is the authentication error that you are getting ? More information will be helpful to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can give your ec2 access to your RDS via IAM Role.

**If want to connect locally.**
No need to pass the credentials via code.

[How can I connect to a private Amazon RDS DB instance from a local machine using an Amazon EC2 instance as a bastion host?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host/)

OR

1. Install aws-cli.
2. Run: aws configure.
3. Add secret and access keys and session tokens, which should have access to your RDS.
   This will add your credentials under the .aws/credentials file(or look for credentials file).
4. Write and run a background process that updates the credentials under credetails file before it expires.

Comment: the application is a lambda function (edited the original question)